# Trouble with a common-class object listener in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, onbeforeunload

I have the following Javascript:

```
function save_data_check(e) {
    var input_value = $('.input-right').text();

    if (input_value !== "") {

        if(!e) e = window.event;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = 'You have unsaved data on this page.'; 

        if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        }

    }

}

window.onbeforeunload = save_data_check;
```

The intended function of this code is to run the function 'save_data_check' when the user tries to leave the page if any input with the common class 'input-right' has any value.

The problem with this function seems to be the most basic part of it: the event listener. Removing the if statement checking if there is any value to the common-class inputs yields the pop-up everytime I try to leave the page?

How am I failing to listen to this event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. `onbeforeunload` is an **unusual** event. You simply return the message you want displayed.
2. `input` elements don't have text, they have a **value**.

So:

```
function save_data_check() {
    var msg;

    $('.input-right').each(function() {
        if (this.value) {
            msg = 'You have unsaved data on this page.';
            return false;
        }
    });

    return msg;
}

window.onbeforeunload = save_data_check;
```

[**Live Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/48c2a0x5/)

Comment: Perfect answer. I'm not sure why I assumed that '.onbeforeload' was not cross-browser. But a quick Google search for that will yield lots of results saying that it isn't.

Comment: @Allenph: It works the same way in all browsers released in the last decade at least. Each of them does the UI differently, and some versions of Firefox don't even show your message (they just show a generic "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved."), but the way they work is consistent.

Comment: @Allenph: Yes, sorry; I've edited that comment. It was fairly misleading the way it was! :-)